# How reliable is MKMapView caching?

Tags: ios, caching, mapkit

I am attempting to integrate a simple map for displaying gps information into a larger ios app. The map should also be available offline.
Prerequisites and what I already know:

- Apple does not offer an API for offline maps
- I cannot use OpenStreetMaps, Mapbox, etc. due to licensing issues

At the moment I am using MKSnapshotter to create a screenshot of the map needed and am drawing on the screenshot. This works fine, however it takes a while for the screenshot to be made and the mapkit api is very comfortable, etc.

One thing I did notice however, is that MapKit caches quite alot of its Map even after closing the application, turning the device off and on, etc., which means that conceivably I could lock zoom, scroll, etc. when the user plans to go offline. This brings me to the question in the title:

How reliable is MKMapView caching?
For how long can I expect it to keep it's cache?